# Batch file timestamp issue

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I had created a batch file for mysql database backup. This runs on windows logon task scheduler.This task does not run if I start the machine around nine'o clock It says access denied, rest of the time it runs. It looks to me that it is between 4 digit of time stamp vs three digit 945 ( for 9.45 ) vs 1045 for (10.45).This is my guess. Please find the code how to resolve the issue. Thanks

```
@ECHO OFF

Echo Avoid Any MYSQL Transcations until backup completes

set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%
md e:\%TIMESTAMP%\am
CD /D d:\\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin\
mysql -s -e "SHOW TABLES FROM amazon" --user=* --password= * --skip-column-names > e:\tables.txt
for /f %%A in (e:\tables.txt) DO (mysqldump --user=* --password= * amazon %%A > e:\%TIMESTAMP%\am\%%A.sql)
mysqldump --user=* --password= *  --no-create-db --no-create-info --no-data --routines am > e:\%TIMESTAMP%\am\procNtrig.sql
CD /D e:\
C:\7zip\7za a  %TIMESTAMP%.zip e:\%TIMESTAMP%\*
RMDIR /S  /q e:\%TIMESTAMP%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to replace space with `0` in the `%TIMESTAMP%` variable. The only time `%time%` has a space in the variable is when it is a single digit character time. `1-9`

So seeing as you only have an issue with time, we can manipulate that specifically.

You should be able to run this with better results.

```
@ECHO OFF

Echo Avoid Any MYSQL Transcations until backup completes

set "times=%time:~0,5%"
set "times=%times::=%"
set "times=%times: =0%"
set "timestamp=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%-%times%

md "e:\%timestamp%\am"
CD /D "d:\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.9\bin\"
mysql -s -e "SHOW TABLES FROM amazon" --user=* --password= * --skip-column-names > e:\tables.txt
for /f %%A in (e:\tables.txt) DO (mysqldump --user=* --password= * amazon %%A > e:\%timestamp%\am\%%A.sql)
mysqldump --user=* --password= *  --no-create-db --no-create-info --no-data --routines am > e:\%timestamp%\am\procNtrig.sql
CD /D e:\
C:\7zip\7za a  %timestamp%.zip e:\%timestamp%\*
RMDIR /S /q "e:\%timestamp%"
```